Let's Encrypt Certbot equivalent with IIS
I want to create a self signed trusted certificate across local network that has no browser warning.
There is Let's encrypt certbot to do this but it works with nginx webserver. Is there any tool to create trusted certificate that works with IIS?

Let's Encrypt is for public domains, not private. "self signed" and "Let's Encrypt" contradict each other. "Let's Encrypt" and "local network" also contradict, unless you use public domains in the local network.

does using a 'a host' record in my DNS Server with the name certbot.int and with my windows server IP Address, considered a public domain? I want to use certbot for an IIS site with the same name: certbot.int

A publicly known domain has a public TLD (which .int is) and is visible in the public DNS. I suspect that you use the TLD ".int" for internal domains - which clearly conflicts which its purpose - see https://tld-list.com/tld/int. So my guess is that what you are trying to do is conflicting with how things should work and you probably need to adjust what you are doing.

Using the DNS-01 challenge to my knowledge it doesn't matter if the server using the certs is accessible form the Internet of not. However the used DNS name have to be public so you have to "buy" a public DNS name on whatever TLS or domain you want. And for the client sie let's encrypt documentation https://letsencrypt.org/docs/client-options/#clients-windows-/-iis

There seem to be two questions here

How to create certificates using Lets Encrypt on an Intranet
How to use Lets Encrypt certificates with Microsoft IIS

Understanding how HTTPS Certificates work
I assume you want to access content in a web browser securely, i.e. using HTTPS, and have "no browser warning".
The warning comes from the fact that when a browser sees an HTTPS site it will attempt to validate that the certificate has come from a reputable source.  Each certificate (except self-signed ones) are signed by another party, and the browser that signer's certificate, and then checks  that signer's certificate, until it reaches a "Root Certificate".  These Root Certificates are very special as they establish the trust chain.  These are installed inside the browser (and shipped by the browser supplier).
So in order to have no warning, you need to have the certificate issues by a certificate authority (such as Lets Encrypt) which is trusted by the Browsers (Lets Encrypt is).
Lets Encrypt allows, for free, you to create a certificate, but it won't allow you to just create a certificate for any domain you like, e.g. microsoft.com.  If it did, that would destroy the trust relationship and Browser suppliers would remove Lets Encrypt's trusted certificate.  So how do I prove that my desire to have a certificate is legitimate?  Let's suppose you want a certificate for mz1378.com...
There are two main methods that Lets Encrypt uses... it either looks up in the DNS record for mz1378.com to check you own it. Or a page on the website  mz1378.com/xxxx.  In both cases Lets Encrypt give you a one time code to put in your DNS or website - proving that you control these things, AND it must be publicly accessible to Lets Encrypt.
How can you do this on an Intranet?
As @Robert said, so long as you buy a Domain Name and have some part host the DNS on the Internet then you can use the DNS method to prove you own that Domain Name and Lets Encrypt will create certificates for you.  Then you'd configure the DNS entry for, say, www.mz1378.com to provide an address for your local web server.  This would have to be the name on the certificate that you just went to all that trouble to obtain.
Use Lets Encrypt certificates with Microsoft IIS
I will leave others to answer how to use Lets Encrypt certificates with Microsoft IIS, otherwise here's a random answer : https://woshub.com/howto-install-free-lets-encrypt-ssl-cert-on-iis/

The main problem is that I don't want to buy a domain to use for internal network. As I tested it is not possible, even if I have an Internal DNS Server.
